# MySQL self-join optimization while calculating move averages

Tags: mysql, optimization, self-join, moving-average

I have created a mysql query to calculate moving averages of data by using multiple self-joins as shown below. This is consuming lot of time and the data rows are in 100k per query. Any way to further optimize it to reduce time please?

```
select a.rownum,a.ma_small_price, b.ma_medium_price from
    (SELECT t3.rownum, AVG(t.last_price) as 'ma_small_price' 
FROM temp_data t3
    left JOIN temp_data t ON t.rownum BETWEEN ifnull(t3.rownum,0) - @psmall AND t3.rownum
GROUP BY t3.rownum) 
inner join
    (SELECT t3.rownum, AVG(t.last_price) as 'ma_medium_price' 
FROM temp_data t3
    left JOIN temp_data t ON t.rownum BETWEEN ifnull(t3.rownum,0) - @pmedium AND t3.rownum
GROUP BY t3.rownum) b on a.rownum = b.rownum
```

[image]

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: *`BETWEEN ifnull(t3.rownum,0) - @psmall AND t3.rownum GROUP BY t3.rownum`* - IFNULL is obviously excess. If t3.rownum IS NULL then BETWEEN will give NULL == FALSE (because its upper limit IS NULL).

Comment: sql server version is 8.0.13

Comment: "sql server" != "mysql"

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OVER ( ... )` is disappointingly slow -- in both MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.x.

I like "exponential moving average" as being easier to compute than "moving average".  The following is roughly equivalent to what Nick proposed.  This runs faster, but has slightly different results:

```
SELECT  rownum,
        @small := @small + 0.5 * (last_price - @small) AS mae_small_price,
        @med   := @med   + 0.2 * (last_price - @med)   AS mae_med_price
    FROM ( SELECT @small := 10, @med := 10 ) AS init
    JOIN temp_data
    ORDER BY rownum;
```

The coefficient controls how fast the exponential moving average adapts to changes in the data.  It should be greater than 0 and less than 1.

The "10" that I initialized the EPA to was a rough guess of the average -- it biases the first few values but is gradually swamped as more values are folded in.

Comment: Thanks Rick...it works pretty fast! I am exploring how EPA would be even useful for my use case.

Comment: @AnkurBansal - Any word on whether EPA is suitable for your application?

Comment: yes, I adjusted the coefficients to find a similar trend as to what MAs were trending to.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running MySQL 8 you should be able to use window functions to get the same result more efficiently. Without seeing sample data it's hard to be 100% certain but this should be close. Note that to use variables in a window frame, you need to use a prepared statement:

```
SET @sql = '
SELECT rownum,
       AVG(last_price) OVER (ORDER BY rownum ROWS BETWEEN ? PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ma_small_price,
       AVG(last_price) OVER (ORDER BY rownum ROWS BETWEEN ? PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ma_medium_price
FROM temp_data';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @psmall, @pmedium;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0845dd38f9223fcd68fa2025e8274bb2)